# Save file to specific path using ie

Tags: vba

My current script:

- Creates IE object `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
- Logs into the website using `ie.document.getelementbyid("login-email").Value`
- Then navigates to URL. URL is not a direct path to file, but it invokes download process (so can't do CTRL+s)

How do I save this file with a custom filepath? XMLHTTP request doesn't seem to work because it doesn't share the session cookies with ie object.

Comment: Can you inspect the page to find the actual download url (using F12 Developer Tools), or is it different each time you load the page? WinHTTP can handle things like cookies and basic access authentication.

Comment: the request url is the same every time, and response header contains the attachment with pdf

Comment: So I've had to deal with a similar situation - it wasn't authentication that forced me to use InternetExplorer, but instead the need to trigger some JavaScript on the page to start the download. What we ended up doing is finding the download notification from IE using Win32 windows functions and sending {ENTER} to download notification to start the Save. What version of IE?

Comment: Something like:
    hWndMain = FindWindowEx(0, 0, "IEFrame", "[title of IE tab]")
    Ret = PostMessage(hWndMain, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, &H53, &H20000000)
    Ret = PostMessage(hWndMain, WM_SYSKEYUP, &H53, &H20000000)

Comment: that doesn't solve the filename/location issue though

Comment: Yeah, what we did is figure out the default filename (it was always the same) and use VBA file commands to move/rename it